# Recursively list subdirectories/files while applying a filter

Tags: java, directory, directory-listing

I have following directory hierarchy

```
$ ls -R a
b   c

a/b:
x.db    y.db

a/b/x.db:
p0.txt  p1.txt

a/b/y.db:

a/c:
m.db

a/c/m.db:
```

I need foo(FIle rootDir){
 ....
}
which outputs `["a/b/x.db", "a/b/y.db", "a/c/m.db"]`

for `foo(new File("a"))`

I have tried using org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils unsuccessfully! 
Following is what I tried

```
private static Collection<File> foo(File rootDir) {
        return FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(rootDir,
                FalseFileFilter.INSTANCE,
                new DirectoryFileFilter() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean accept(File file) {
                        if (file.getName().endsWith("db")) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

This outputs

```
[<parent_dir>/a]
```

Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: There's two instances of `y.db`. Shouldn't the last be `m.db`?

Comment: What specifically have you tried with commons-io and what issues did you encounter?

Comment: @BartKiers Sorry for the typo. Edited with correction.

Comment: @BrettOkken edited the question and added snippet of what I tried with  org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

Answer (score 0):

```
public void findFile(File dir){
   for(File f: dir.listFiles()){
       if(f.isDirectory()){
           findFile(f);
       }else if(f.getName().endsWith(".db")){
           System.out.prinltn(f.getName());
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: who did the down vote and why, now you're preventing me from posting my own questions...

Comment: Thanks for you answer, however since I intend to use this in production code,  was looking for some standard utility for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

See the Java tutorial [Walking the File Tree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html).

In particular look at [Finding Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html).

The example code [find.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/Find.java) "recurses a file tree looking for files and directories that match a particular glob (filter) pattern."